# SQL Conditionally selelct one or two rows based on a shared column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have devices that attempt to pass tests. When they do i get an insert into the DB of the device, test, pass or fail, and a time stamp. What I want is to select All of the passes and fails but I don't want a failure if there has been a pass. If there have been multiple failures of one test and no passes, I only want the most recent failure.

Two examples. There are 4 rows of the table:

`Device Test Pass TimeStamp`

```
X       T1   0   some time
X       T1   1   some time

Y       T2   0   some time
Y       T2   0   some time
```

I want to select only X when it passes, I don't want the failure since it has now passed. For Y I want the most recent failure. I would appreciate even a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @mucio a union all on self with a where clause that couldn't reference my table aliases. A bunch of stuff that doesn't work really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prioritization query with a twist can do this with window functions or `union all`.  Let's go for the second approach:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.pass = 1
union all
(select top (1) with ties t.*
 from t
 where t.pass = 0 and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.device = t.device and t2.test = t.test and t2.pass = 1)
 order by device, test, row_number() over (order by timestamp desc)
)
```

Or, more simply as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by by device, test
                          order by pass desc,
                                   (case when pass = 0 then timestamp end) desc
                         ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The intention for the `rank()` is that all passes will be first and have a rank value of 1 -- if present.  If there are none, then only the most recent fail will have a rank of 1.

Comment: so that's union all and is the second select supposed to be aliased as t2? at `select 1 from t t2` i get t is invalid object. In SQL server. tried replacing with a cross join.

Comment: @ScottClark . . . Except for the misspelling on `all`, the query is written as I intend.

Comment: This has helped me tremendously. A great introduction to the rank function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the union all approach with CTE's to promote readability with the separate grouping and filtering presuming a reasonable data set size.

```
;with LatestPassingTests as
(
    select  
        Device,
        Test,
        Pass,
        max([Timestamp]) as 'Timestamp'
    from t                
    where Pass = 1
    group by Device, Test, Pass
),
DeduplicatedTestResults
as
(
    select 
        Device,
        Test,
        Pass,
        [Timestamp]
    from LatestPassingTests        
    union all
    select  
        t.Device,
        t.Test,
        t.Pass,
        max(t.[Timestamp]) as 'Timestamp'
    from @tempstuff as t
        left outer join LatestPassingTests as p on (t.Device = p.Device)
    where p.Device is null
    group by t.Device, t.Test, t.Pass
)
select  
    Device,
    Test,
    Pass,
    [Timestamp] 
from DeduplicatedTestResults
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no possibility of fail after pass within the same device and test just use a simple inner query with max time:

```
select Device, Test, Pass, TimeStamp from table 
join (
select Device, Test, max(Timstamp) as TimeStamp from table group by 1,2 ) t1
on t1.Device=table.Device and t1.Test=table.Test and t1.TimeStamp =table.TimeStamp
```

If there is a possibility to fail after pass within the same device and test and you want only the pass, 2 inner joins are needed:

```
select Device, Test, Pass, TimeStamp from table join (
select Device, Test, Pass, max(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp from table 
join (
select Device, Test, max(Pass) as Pass from table group by 1,2 ) t1
on t1.Device=table.Device and t1.Test=table.Test and t1.Pass =table.Pass
group by 1,2,3 ) t2
on t2.Device=table.Device and t2.Test=table.Test and t2.Pass =table.Pass and t2.TimeStamp =table.TimeStamp
```